# Z3 -smt2 -in: Get Z3 version

Tags: version, stdin, z3

Can I get the version of Z3 after starting it with the options `-smt2 -in`? Something like

```
(get-z3-version)
; Z3 4.3.2 x64  // Desired reply
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SMT-LIB 2.0 front-end, we can use the command

`(get-info :version)`

This command is part of the standard, and should also work for other solvers.
We can test the command [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Gct).

We can also use the command line option `-version`. Example:

```
  z3 -version
  >> Z3 version 4.3.1
```

Comment: Thanks, Leo! FYI: The versions returned by the two methods differ. Using Z3 [version 4.3.2 - 64 bit - build hashcode 96f4606a7f2d], I get `Z3 version 4.3.2` from `z3 -version` and `(:version "4.3")` from `(get-info :version)`. Is that intended? For what it's worth, I'd prefer to get the precise version.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this problem. I will fix it.