# How can I know the version of a library in Google Colab? Trying it for Z3

Tags: python, pip, version, google-colaboratory, z3

I know I can manually install a concrete version of a library in Google Colab (see [When I install older version of scikit-learn in Google Colab, it still import the newest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67612665/when-i-install-older-version-of-scikit-learn-in-google-colab-it-still-import-th)).

However, how can I know which version of a library I am using? I am trying to know which version of `Z3` I am using.

I tested the following:

```
pip install z3-solver
import z3
z3 -version
```

But I get the following error: `name 'version' is not defined`

In my (Unix) machine, it suffices to ask: `z3 -version` (see [Z3 -smt2 -in: Get Z3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882140/z3-smt2-in-get-z3-version))

This question is extensible to any library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the dunder notation

```py
z3.__version__
```

EDIT - for pip package `z3-solver`

you should use

```py
import z3
z3.get_version_string()
```

as seen [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I tested that and received the error: `module 'z3' has no attribute '__version__'`

Comment: Indeed, it seems it does not follow conventionnal module dunder

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! So, for asking versions, there is no general method for Colab, but specific methods for each library.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to know which version of Z3 I am using.(...)This question is extensible to any library.

Then do not rely on library to report that, but `pip`. You might simply instruct `pip` to `list` all installed modules and find version of interesting one, that is

```
pip install z3-solver
pip list
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! However, with this, I get the error: `invalid syntax`

Comment: you need to add ! in front of pip